# Ansible, Boto, AWS - Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].memory

Tags: ansible, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have several services running in docker containers on Amazon ECS and am assigning percentages of the total system memory for each service.

In my ansible/roles/ecs_cluster_init/defaults/main.yaml file I have the following entries:

```
docker_memory_limit_service1: 17
docker_memory_limit_service2: 12
docker_memory_limit_service3: 16
docker_memory_limit_service4: 10
docker_memory_limit_service5: 16
docker_memory_limit_service6: 10
total_system_memory : 2048
```

Service1 should get 17% of the total system memory while service 4 only gets 10%. This is to easily accommodate changes in instance sizes.

In my ansible/roles/ecs_cluster_init/vars/main.yaml file I have (partial portion):

```
ecs_task_definitions:
  - name: "service1"
    elb: "{{ elb_creation_output.results[0].elb.dns_name }}"
    image: "{{ service1_docker_image }}"
    port: "{{ ports.service1 }}"
    memory: "{{ ( total_system_memory * ( docker_memory_limit_service1|int / 100 ))|int|abs }}"
```

To ensure clarity, the service memory value is turned into a percentage (by dividing by 100) and then determining that portion of the total system memory.

In my ansible/roles/ecs_cluster_init/tasks/main.yaml file I have:

```
## ECS Task and Service Definitions
- block:
    - name: Create ECS Service1 Task Definitions
      ecs_taskdefinition:
        region: "{{ region }}"
        containers:
          - name: "{{ item.name }}"
            cpu: 0
            essential: true
            image: "{{ item.image }}"
            memory: {{ item.memory|int|abs }}
            mountPoints: "{{ item.mounts }}"
            environment: "{{ item.env_vars }}"
            portMappings: "{{ item.portmap }}"
            entryPoint:
              - "java"
              - "-Xms{{ java_heap_size_initial }}"
              - "-Xmx{{ java_heap_size_max }}"
              - "-DlogDir=/host"
              - "-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false"
              - "-jar"
              - "/app.jar"
            logConfiguration:
              logDriver: "{{ ecs_task_log_configuration.logDriver }}"
              options:
                max-size: "{{ ecs_task_log_configuration.options.max_size }}"
                max-file: "{{ ecs_task_log_configuration.options.max_file }}"
        family: "{{ service_prefix }}-{{ item.name }}-{{ env_name }}"
        state: present
        increment_revision: true
        volumes: "{{ item.volumes }}"
      register: service1_task_definition
      with_items: "{{ ecs_task_definitions }}"
```

When I run the playbook for the role I receive the following error:

```
TASK [ecs_cluster_create : Create ECS Service1 Task Definitions] ****************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].memory, value: 204, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or where I'm missing specifying the memory value should be an int?

Comment: You can try to add `|to_json` filter `{{ item.memory|int|to_json }}`

Comment: I still received the same error message after applying your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue with Ansible/Jinja that you can't preserve `int` type after templating.
In other words `|int` is integer inside double braces, but become string when you close braces.

But Ansible preserves complex types like dicts/list after templating, so you may do this trick:

```
- name: Create ECS Service1 Task Definitions
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    containers: "{{'['+dict(name=item.name, cpu=0, image=item.image, memory=item.memory|int)|to_json+']'}}"
  with_items: "{{ ecs_task_definitions }}"
```

*I've shortened the example*.

This way we construct a string that is a JSON-list which ansible converts after templating.

Comment: What does the '+' after the to_json filter do?

Comment: `dict(...)|to_json` gives you JSON-string, then you add `[` and `]` to both sides with `+` string concatenation, because containers should be a list (as per your example).

Comment: How would I format the container list if it also contains a list? I have updated my original question to show the entryPoint list of which I am referring to.

Comment: See [lists](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) in Python. But in your case it'll be convenient to use `entryPoint=('java^-Xms'+java_heap_size_initial+'^...^/app.jar').split('^')`. I used `^` character as nonexistent in any argument to form a single string and then split it into list.

Comment: Thank you for the additional follow-up and link. The formatting is what I'm not getting. Does this look correct for the entire container definition or am I still wrong?  `"{{'['+dict(name=item.name,cpu=0,essential=true,image=item.image,memory=item.memory|int,mountPoints=item.mounts,environment=item.env_vars,portMappings=item.portmap,entryPoint=('java^-Xms{{ java_heap_size_initial }}^-Xmx{{ java_heap_size_max }}^-DlogDir=/host^-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom^-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false^-jar^/app.jar').split('^'))|to_json+']'}}^`

Comment: You can't do nested templating, so `entryPoint=('jav‌​a^-Xms'+java_heap_size_initial+'^-Xmx'+java_heap_size_max+'^-DlogDir=/host^-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom^-D‌​com.sun.net.ssl.chec‌​kRevocation=false^-j‌​ar^/app.jar').split(‌​'^')`. This is ugly, I know...

Comment: I will create another question as you have answer my original. Thank you.

Comment: In case you're interested I created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985245/how-to-combine-json-dictionary-and-lists-in-jinja-template