# How to combine json dictionary and lists in jinja template

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

This is a follow-up to the excellent answer that I received in [Ansible, Boto, AWS - Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915660/ansible-boto-aws-invalid-type-for-parameter-containerdefinitions0-memory).

I am not understanding how to combine the provided answer(s) properly.

In my original ansible/roles/ecs_cluster_init/tasks/main.yaml file I have:

```
## ECS Task and Service Definitions
- block:
    - name: Create ECS Service1 Task Definitions
      ecs_taskdefinition:
        region: "{{ region }}"
        containers:
          - name: "{{ item.name }}"
            cpu: 0
            essential: true
            image: "{{ item.image }}"
            memory: "{{ item.memory|int|abs }}"
            mountPoints: "{{ item.mounts }}"
            environment: "{{ item.env_vars }}"
            portMappings: "{{ item.portmap }}"
            entryPoint:
              - "java"
              - "-Xms{{ java_heap_size_initial }}"
              - "-Xmx{{ java_heap_size_max }}"
              - "-DlogDir=/host"
              - "-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false"
              - "-jar"
              - "/app.jar"
            logConfiguration:
              logDriver: "{{ ecs_task_log_configuration.logDriver }}"
              options:
                max-size: "{{ ecs_task_log_configuration.options.max_size }}"
                max-file: "{{ ecs_task_log_configuration.options.max_file }}"
        family: "{{ service_prefix }}-{{ item.name }}-{{ env_name }}"
        state: present
        increment_revision: true
        volumes: "{{ item.volumes }}"
      register: service1_task_definition
      with_items: "{{ ecs_task_definitions }}"
```

The initial answer that works for the services without an entryPoint was to do:

```
- name: Create ECS Service1 Task Definitions
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    containers: "{{'['+dict(name=item.name, cpu=0, image=item.image, memory=item.memory|int)|to_json+']'}}"
  with_items: "{{ ecs_task_definitions }}"
```

and the answer for how to handle the entryPoint key was:

```
entryPoint=('jav‌​a^-Xms'+java_heap_size_initial+'^-Xmx'+jav‌​a_heap_size_max+'^-D‌​logDir=/host^-Djava.‌​security.egd=file:/d‌​ev/./urandom^-D‌​com‌​.sun.net.ssl.chec‌​k‌​Revocation=false^-j‌‌​​ar^/app.jar').split‌​(‌​'^')
```

What I'm not getting is how to combine the two in my ansible/roles/ecs_cluster_init/tasks/main.yaml file. How do I get the entryPoint and subsequent logConfiguration lists into the container dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on ansible ≥ 1.8.4 or can upgrade to that version (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5865), you can just add quotes around `memory`:

```
memory: "{{ item.memory|int|abs|int }}"
```

But if you want to do this the hard way:

```
- name: Create ECS Service1 Task Definitions
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    containers: "{{'['+dict(name=item.name, cpu=0, image=item.image, memory=item.memory, entryPoint=[ 'java', '-Xms'+java_heap_size_initial, '-Xmx'+java_heap_size_max, '-DlogDir=/host', '-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom', '-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false', '-jar', '/app.jar' ], logConfiguration=dict(logDriver=ecs_task_log_configuration.logDriver, options={ 'max-size': ecs_task_log_configuration.options.max_size, 'max-file': ecs_task_log_configuration.options.max_file}))|to_json+']'}}"
  with_items: "{{ ecs_task_definitions }}"
```

Comment: I definitely prefer the easy way but I still receive the "Invalid Type" error message when using `memory: "{{ item.memory|int|abs|int }}"`.

Comment: Using the "hard way" I receive the error `template error while templating string: unexpected char u'\\u200c'`. The 200 is the memory value but I'm not sure where the following "c" is coming from unless that is being added by the template / filter.

Comment: `\u200c is a zero width non joiner`.  This is probably an artifact of copy & paste.  I am looking into it now.

Comment: It looks like copy & paste brought over some super weird control characters.  The last update should (hopefully) help address those issues.

Comment: Also, @DaemonofChaos:  what version of ansible are you using?

Comment: I'm running Anisible 2.2.0. The `|int` filter for item.memory isn't needed?

Comment: Nope.  I think the easy way will work without the extra filters, too, if you want to try that . . .

Comment: I did try the easy way first; both what was posted here and in my original question (link provided at top of question) and it never worked. I did have to add the `|int` filter back to memory to get it working. Thank you for all of the help!